# Why Does This Timer Code For Ruby Make my Computer Work So Hard?

Tags: ruby, timer

```
time_limit = gets.to_f * 60
start_time = Time.new
end_time = start_time + time_limit
x = 1
until Time.new >= end_time
  time_left = end_time - Time.new
  time_left_in_minutes = time_left / 60
  puts "Minutes Left: #{time_left_in_minutes}"
end
until x == 0
puts "Time Since End of #{time_limit / 60} Minutes: #{Time.new - end_time}"
end
```

My computer fan spins up to full speed and my computer gets noisy running this code. Is there a better way to do this that isn't as much work for a processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're asking your processor to do a lot of work!

Look at your loop:

```
until Time.new >= end_time
  time_left = end_time - Time.new
  time_left_in_minutes = time_left / 60
  puts "Minutes Left: #{time_left_in_minutes}"
end
```

That just spins and spins and spins until the time limit is reached.  Your processor just keeps going and going. (You're also doing some things which are expensive in here - you call `Time.new` twice on each iteration, and object creation can be expensive - but if your loop was faster you'd just spin faster.)

You probably need to add a delay in that loop, so that it only runs once a second, or once a minute, or something like that.  `sleep 30` will pause for 30 seconds, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer gets hot because you are busy-looping while waiting for the timeout.

The easiest solution: Add a sleep(1) in the loop. This will cause it to be run once per second instead of as fast as possible.

You could also just sleep the correct number of seconds instead.

Then, after waiting for a certain time you also busy-loop, until x somehow gets to be 0. This will also use a lot of CPU.